# aDrawable.SetBounds(...) doesn't work

Tags: android, overlay, drawable, osmdroid, setbounds

I can't succeed to put a custom centered overlay item on my map. It always appears centered on bottom and middle. Here is my code:

------------My overlay item class-------------

```
public class EditionThumbOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {

    public EditionThumbOverlayItem(GeoPoint aGeoPoint, Resources resources) {
        super("", "", aGeoPoint);
        Drawable pinThumbDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_thumb);
        pinThumbDrawable.setBounds(pinThumbDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * (-2 / 5),
                pinThumbDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * (-2 / 5), pinThumbDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 3 / 5,
                pinThumbDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 3 / 5);
        setMarker(pinThumbDrawable);
    }

}
```

-------------my itemized overlay class-----------------

```
public class PinThumbOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    // Only one item can be set on this overlay
    private OverlayItem mEditionThumb;

    public PinThumbOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker, ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
        super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2, IMapView arg3) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
        return mEditionThumb;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        if (mEditionThumb == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mEditionThumb = overlay;
        populate();
    }

    public void removeOverlayItem() {
        mEditionThumb = null;
        populate();
    }
}
```

-----------------itemized overlay creation----------------------

```
DefaultResourceProxyImpl defaultResouceProxyImpl = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
Drawable defaultPinEdition = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_thumb);
                mPinThumbOverlay = new PinThumbOverlay(defaultPinEdition, defaultResouceProxyImpl);
mMapView.getOverlays().clear();
mMapView.getOverlays().add(mPinThumbOverlay);
```

-------------------Overlay item creation-------------------------

```
EditionThumbOverlayItem editionThumb = new EditionThumbOverlayItem(new GeoPoint(mCurrentUserLocation),
                getResources());
        mPinThumbOverlay.addOverlayItem(editionThumb);
```

As a note: I use osmdroid map, not default google map api.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that osmdroid overwrites any values you set with the drawble.setBounds() method in the onDrawItem method in ItemizedOverlay:

```
protected void onDrawItem(final Canvas canvas, final Item item, final Point curScreenCoords) {
    final int state = (mDrawFocusedItem && (mFocusedItem == item) ? OverlayItem.ITEM_STATE_FOCUSED_MASK
            : 0);
    final Drawable marker = (item.getMarker(state) == null) ? getDefaultMarker(state) : item
            .getMarker(state);
    final HotspotPlace hotspot = item.getMarkerHotspot();

    boundToHotspot(marker, hotspot);

    // draw it
    Overlay.drawAt(canvas, marker, curScreenCoords.x, curScreenCoords.y, false);
}
```

Or rather, the actual overwriting will be done in the boundToHotspot(marker,hotspot); method.

To overcome this set your hotspot on your OverlayItem instead of setting the bounds on the drawable. 
Example:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(currentLoc);
OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem("my location", "my loc", point);
item.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

This should produce the result your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to put a marker in the map center, use this code snippet:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext()); 

        GeoPoint location = getLocation()
        ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> currentLocationOverlay; 
        Drawable marker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_marker);
        OverlayItem myLocationOverlayItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "Current Position", location); 
        myLocationOverlayItem.setMarker(marker);  
        final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        items.add(myLocationOverlayItem);
        currentLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
                new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }, resourceProxy);        

     mapView.getOverlays().add(this.currentLocationOverlay);
     mapView.getController().setCenter(location);

 }
```